# Actionbar shows dropdown when only one item in the menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

Im using app compat theme in my app, and in the actionbar I have a menu with one item that should be shown as an icon - but instead I get menu button like this

[image]

Here is my code of the menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_play"
        android:icon="@drawable/play"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

And here is the code on how I initialize the actionbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and show the menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.names, menu);
        playStop = menu.findItem(R.id.action_play);
        return true;
    }
```

So can someone help me to display the menu item as it should?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure icon initialisation is proper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using support library, `android:showAsAction` will not do its task. So your menu declaration is not correct. From [***documentation***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

If there's not enough room for the item in the action bar, it will appear in the action overflow.

> ***Using XML attributes from the support library***
>
> *Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.*

---

So your menu xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_play"
        android:icon="@drawable/play"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is valid only when you use the support library. If you are using the default ```ActionBar``` the original code posted in the question will work.

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov Yes you are correct. This was into definition too, and now I have updated answer and added it on first line also. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

rather than

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```